# Modifying validation function for single image instead of Tencrop

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have a `PublicTest` function that runs every epoch for validation and there is a `transform test` variable that transforms the validation data as above:

```
    transform_test = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.TenCrop(cut_size),
    transforms.Lambda(lambda crops: torch.stack([transforms.ToTensor()(crop) for crop in crops])),
])  

def PublicTest(epoch):
    global PublicTest_acc
    global best_PublicTest_acc
    global best_PublicTest_acc_epoch
    net.eval()
    PublicTest_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(PublicTestloader):
        bs, ncrops, c, h, w = np.shape(inputs)
        inputs = inputs.view(-1, c, h, w)
        if use_cuda:
            inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
        inputs, targets = Variable(inputs, volatile=True), Variable(targets)
        outputs = net(inputs)
        outputs_avg = outputs.view(bs, ncrops, -1).mean(1)  # avg over crops
        loss = criterion(outputs_avg, targets)
        PublicTest_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs_avg.data, 1)
        total += targets.size(0)
        correct += predicted.eq(targets.data).cpu().sum()

        utils.progress_bar(batch_idx, len(PublicTestloader), 'Loss: %.3f | Acc: %.3f%% (%d/%d)'
                           % (PublicTest_loss / (batch_idx + 1), 100. * correct / total, correct, total))
```

I'd like to modify the code so instead of `Tencrop` each image would be validated once. I changed the `transform_test` like this

```
 transform_test = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
```

I run the code but had the realized that `PublicTest` have `ncrops` as a parameter and received the error:

```
 File "mainpro_FER.py", line 147, in PublicTest
    bs, ncrops, c, h, w = np.shape(inputs)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)
```

removed `ncrops` parameter in the function, tried again had this error:

> IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

So I need a way to make this function work for single image for every images in batch unlike TenCrop. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, I figured out just like this:

```
def PublicTest(epoch):
    global PublicTest_acc
    global best_PublicTest_acc
    global best_PublicTest_acc_epoch
    net.eval()
    PublicTest_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(PublicTestloader):
        bs, c, h, w = np.shape(inputs)
        inputs = inputs.view(-1, c, h, w)
        if use_cuda:
            inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
        inputs, targets = Variable(inputs, volatile=True), Variable(targets)
        outputs = net(inputs)
        # outputs_avg = outputs.view(bs, ncrops, -1).mean(1)  # avg over crops
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        PublicTest_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += targets.size(0)
        correct += predicted.eq(targets.data).cpu().sum()

        utils.progress_bar(batch_idx, len(PublicTestloader), 'Loss: %.3f | Acc: %.3f%% (%d/%d)'
                           % (PublicTest_loss / (batch_idx + 1), 100. * correct / total, correct, total))
```